# BootStrap resize navBar height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In this sample of bootstrap [navbar-default](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) , I can not resize height of that.This height is big . How to resize that with bootstrap class's ?

for example:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The default css for the class `form-control` that bootstrap has is there is height and a padding so I suggest overwrite that with your preferred height. Give textbox and button a class you want like.

```
.someclass { 
   height: auto !important;
   padding: 5px; //manipulate this
}
```

or

```
.someclass { 
   height: 20px !important; //manipulate this
}
```

See example [here](http://bootply.com/109229#)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you placing the same in  or  tag . These directly pick up the attributes along with the usage of variopus classes . For example try this one -

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
<form  class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form> </header>
```